# JodaTime allows invalid date

Tags: java, jodatime

I expected this to throw an exception because the 1st of February 2016 is not a Friday:

```
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEEE, d MMMM yyyy");
final DateTime date = formatter.parseDateTime("Friday, 1 February 2016");
System.out.println(formatter.print(date));
```

Instead, it printed out `Friday, 5 February 2016`. What am I missing here?

Comment: This is a known bug in Joda-Time which will not be fixed for sake of preserving backwards compatibility. The new `java.time`-API (or my lib Time4J) can correctly validate such dates as invalid (at least in strict mode).

Comment: See also https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/issues/447

Comment: Moving over to java.time now, which doesn't have this issue. Strangely, I ran across some old Jodatime validation code of mine from a couple of years ago where I parsed a date (that had a week day in it) and then converted it back to text and compared the original string.. obviously to guard against this very issue. I had forgotten about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's explained in the doc (http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

> Parsing builds up the resultant instant by 'setting' the value of each parsed field from largest to smallest onto an initial instant, typically 1970-01-01T00:00Z. This design means that day-of-month is set before day-of-week. As such, if both the day-of-month and day-of-week are parsed, and the day-of-week is incorrect, **then the day-of-week overrides the day-of-month**. This has a side effect if the input is not consistent.